# Free the buffer inside a function or inside main

Tags: c

Today i was trying to write a program and i realized that i need one file to be read in more places inside my program, but before i got there i had the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *printFile(char *fileName){
    long int length;
    char *buffer;
    size_t size;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen (fileName , "r" );


    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (file);
    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_SET);

    buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*(size_t)length);
    if (buffer == NULL){
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        exit (2);
    }


    size = fread (buffer,1,(size_t) length,file);
    if (size != (size_t)length){
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        exit(3);
    }

    fclose (file);
    return buffer;
}

int main (void) {
    char *fileName = "test.txt";
    char *fileContent = printFile(fileName);

    printf("%s", fileContent);

    free(fileContent);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see i have used free in the main function, and after i realized that that's not ok for my program I decided to free that buffer inside the printFile function, and I now have this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *printFile(char *fileName){
    long int length;
    char *buffer,*buffer2;
    size_t size;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen (fileName , "r" );
    if (file == NULL){
        fputs ("File error",stderr);
        fclose (file);
        exit (1);
    }

    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (file);
    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_SET);

    buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*(size_t)length);
    if (buffer == NULL){
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        exit (2);
    }

    buffer2 = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*(size_t)length);
    if (buffer2 == NULL){
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        exit (2);
    }

    size = fread (buffer,1,(size_t) length,file);
    if (size != (size_t)length){
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        exit(3);
    }

    strcpy (buffer2, buffer);
    fclose (file);
    free(buffer);

    return buffer2;
}

int main (void) {
    char *fileName = "test.txt";
    char *fileContent = printFile(fileName);

    printf("%s", fileContent);

    return 0;
}
```

As you probably noticed i used a second pointer (*buffer2) to copy the content of the first buffer inside of it before I free it the first one.

My question is:
is my approach right or wrong?

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends! `sizeof(char)` is _defined_ by the standard to yield `1`. That will never differ.

Comment: you mean (char *) in front of malloc ?

Comment: SO is not a code review site. If your code is atually working, you might migrate to code review, but first read their FAQ if that is appropriate. If you have a specific problem, please post a [mcve].

Comment: I mean casting `void *` to another pointer. (and `sizeof(char)`)

Comment: Sorry, i thought that I was explaining enough, and i also showed my code, the question was if i copying buffer to buffer2 and then freeing the main buffer was a good approach. There was no code review my intention. My bad if i did something wrong.

Comment: @Michi if your code works as intended and you're wondering if there's a better way to do the same thing, that's *exactly* what [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is for!

Comment: i did a wrong approch of the problem, i was only intended somehow to return the content of that file through that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to memory management!

The question you should be asking is: why would your second approach be superior to the former? You free `buffer`, but then you return `buffer2`, and someone has to free `buffer2`, so you are in exactly the same position as before, except that you copied the file contents twice.

If you don't want to allocate memory inside `printFile()`, then force the caller to pass in a buffer. In other words, shift the responsibility of dealing with allocation to whatever code uses `printFile()`. Of course, now the caller has to worry about allocating a buffer that is large enough (although it is easy to get the file size with `stat(2)`, or with stdio wrappers like you did).

Whatever method you end up using, you just can't run away from memory management when you start using dynamic allocation: someone, somewhere, will have to be responsible for freeing memory.

Comment: I think i understand now. I only wanted to return the content of that file, that was all my intention.

Comment: @Michi I think your original approach is enough. Just make sure you don't forget to free the buffer once you're done - although it might be irrelevant on this short-living program, it's usually good practice.

Comment: The problem remains now what Olaf sayed: "Standard warning: Do not cast void * as returned by malloc & friends! sizeof(char) is defined by the standard to yield 1. That will never differ. "  i removed this: (char *)  if this is what he meant. 

I just do not understand what he sayed.

Comment: @Michi He's saying that instead of doing `buffer = (char *) malloc(...)` you should simply do `buffer = malloc(...)`. You don't need the explicit `(char *)` cast. To see why this is bad practice, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @Michi About `sizeof`, he's saying that `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you don't need to use that. So instead of `malloc(sizeof(char)*(size_t)length);` you can use the shorter version `malloc(length);`.

Comment: if i use "malloc(length);" i get: "error: conversion to ‘size_t’ from ‘long int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]|" so i need to cast length, works only this: "buffer = malloc((size_t)length);"

Comment: @Michi: **Please** read a C book to get the prases right. As you are using `malloc`, you shoudl already know what `void *` and what a _cast_ is. These are vital terms when using C and understanding any literature. It is a very bad idea to refer to "casting the result of malloc" as "that thing in parenthesis before the word `malloc`". That way you will never really understand what you are doing - and have a very flat learning-curve.

Comment: I started to read that book you gave me yesterday, and so i got to succed this program today. i use gcc options: "-Wall -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion"

Comment: @Michi Ah yeah, that's right, you'll need to do that. But by all means, do take the time to read a good C book. It's well worth it, and I'm sure you'll master the language quickly.

Comment: @Michi: (note: please add `@addressee` to talk to someone. Otherwise your peer will not be notified about your comment). `-W` is the deprecated old version of `-Wextra`. You should also compile C99 or - better C11 code (`-std=C11` or `-std=gnu11` if you want gcc extensions (some are very useful) ). C99/C11 mode implies `-Wstrict-prototypes` as that is part of the newer C standards. Notet that gcc since 5.1 defaults to C11 (C90 for older versions). `-g` is not a warning, but adds debugging symbols. You might want to optimize: `-Og` (since 4.8 iirc) while debugging. ...

Comment: @Michi: ... The default is `-O2` iirc, which makes debugging complicated to impossible.

Comment: @Olaf i get: "gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=C11’"

Comment: @Michi: Which version of gcc are you using actually? Must be pretty old. Hmm... try lowercase.× (man, please think a bit for yourself. There is quite a good documentation for gcc).

Comment: @ Olaf I use: "gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2"  and yes, it is working with lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can be improved.

Instead of

```
char *printFile(char *fileName);
```

Use two functions,

```
char *getFileContents(char *fileName);
void printFile(char *fileName);
```

With the understanding that `getFileContents` returns memory that needs to be `free`d by users of the function. `printFile()`, and other functions can call `getFileContents()`, can do with the contents as they please and then call `free()` on the memory.

Also, when there is an error in reading the contents of the file, return `NULL` instead of calling `exit()`.

```
char *getFileContents(char *fileName)
{
   long int length;
   char *buffer;
   size_t size;
   FILE *file;

   file = fopen (fileName , "r" );
   if (file == NULL){
      fputs ("File error",stderr);
      return NULL;
   }

   fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
   length = ftell (file);
   fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_SET);

   buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*(size_t)length);
   if (buffer == NULL){
      fclose (file);
      fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
      return NULL;
   }

   size = fread (buffer,1,(size_t) length,file);
   if (size != (size_t)length){
      fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
      fclose (file);
      return NULL;
   }

   fclose (file);

   return buffer;
}

char *printFile(char *fileName)
{
   char* fileContents = getFileContents(fileName);
   if ( NULL != fileContents )
   {
      printf("%s", fileContents);
      free(fileContents);
   }
}
```

Comment: The better approach will be to free that pointer just after i do not need that content of that file anymore, in this case the first approach (my first code) it should be enough. isn't it ?

Comment: @Michi, I agree with that assessment.